# C#でのSwitch式で同処理を複数条件下で分岐したい場合

Tags: c#, .net-core

以下のようなコードで値が0と1の時の処理をまとめたいのですが、Switch式でそれは可能でしょうか？環境は、.Net Core 3.0です。

```
var res = val switch {
  0 => A(),
  1 => A(),
  2 => B(),
  _ => throw new Exception()
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

出来ない状況に変わりは無いですが、C# 9.0に向けて機能追加が議論されているようです。

[Multiple switch cases? #15241](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/15241)
[Proposed changes for Pattern Matching in C# 9.0 - Draft Specification #2850](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2850)
いろんな書き方が提案され、結構長い記事になっています。

以下は @sayuri さん回答と同等内容の英語版記事
[c# 8 switch expression multiple cases with same result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56676260/9014308)

こちらは C# 9.0への提案に言及した記事
[Multiple cases in c# 8.0 switch expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55510463/9014308)

Comment: .Net Coreにも移行しましたし、C#9.0を心待ちにすることにします。情報ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

F#だとORパターンがあるので書けるんですが、

```
let res = match ``val`` with
          | 0 | 1 -> A()
          | 2     -> B ()
          | _     -> failwith ""
```

C#だとパターンは発展途上なため書きようがないかも。

```
var res = val switch {
  _ when val == 0 || val == 1 => A(),
  2 => B(),
  _ => throw new Exception(),
};
```

Comment: 今後のC#に期待ですね。回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

三項演算子(ternary operator)を使う方法も考えられます。

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        test(0);
        test(1);
        test(2);
        test(3);
    }

    static void test(int val) {
        var res = (val == 1 ? 0 : val) switch {
            0 => A(), // 0 or 1
            2 => B(),
            _ => throw new Exception()
        };
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", val, res);
    }

    static string A() { return "A"; }
    static string B() { return "B"; }
}
```

**実行結果**

```
0: A
1: A
2: B
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at Program.test(Int32 val)
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

Playground: [C# Online Compiler | .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w4wEQB)

Comment: そうですね、諦めて三項演算子で対応いたします。回答ありがとうございました。